# how to load and process a text file with many rows one by one in a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops, dataframe

Have a CSV file with 10000 rows. Have to take a single row and put it in a function and process it. Like that it should go on until 10k rows get completed.

for Ex :

print(abcd) gets me 10k rows

```
  1264984
  8765132
  654651321
  ......
  ......
  ......
```

take the first row and put it in this function for processing

```
     def main():
           16541+(first row)
```

return the result

next, go for the second row

```
    def main():
           16541+(second row)
```

like that it should go on till 10 rows get completed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `chunksize` option, in the `pandas` [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) function.

The `chunksize` specifies the number of rows to read in at a time. Therefore, by setting it to 1 you are able to achieve a row-by-row processing.

```
import pandas as pd    
chunksize = 1
for chunk in pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=chunksize):
    do_something(chunk)
    print(111+chunk["col1"])
```

In this case, `do_something` could be any function which you would like to call. Also note, that within each loop of the `for-loop`, `chunk` is a `pandas` dataframe therefore you can use all the existing functionality of `pandas`.

Comment: In place of procees(chunk )  can i create a func

Comment: @hukkemaaruspetus yes you can, I have updated it to illustrate more usage.

Comment: "col1" is the name of the column of your dataframe which contains your numbers. The column names are usually the first time in a csv, if not you can define them yourself using `names` parameters in `read_csv`. Without sample data, its very difficult to say what your column names would be.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that for some reason you prefer to read line by line and not use `pandas`, you can do the following:

```
import csv

def main(num):    
     return 16541+num

dataset=list()
with open('.yourcsv.csv', 'r') as f:
    df=csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    for row in df:
       #following your example:
       main(row[0].astype(int)) #assuming, as in your example, that you only have one element per row
       #alternatively you can also create a dataset by appending the rows iteratively
       dataset.append(row)
```

Of course you first need to define your function `main()` and have it accept one input

```
def main(num):    
     return 16541+num
```

The function accepts one input, which we identify throughout the function as `num`. When we insert the variable `row` as input what Python actually does is:

```
main(num=row)
```

So `num` gets created by assigning the variable `row` to it

Comment: Can you add def main(num) func in  dataset.append(row). Its little confusing

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

Comment: @hukkemaaruspetus that's because your input `row` is a list of strings by default. you need to transform it to int: `row[0].astype(int)`. I updated the answer